# How can I read and manipulate PDF 1.5 files in Perl?

Tags: perl, pdf

There doesn't appear to be any Perl libraries that can open, manipulate, and re-save PDF documents that use the newer PDF version (1.5 and above I believe) that use a cross-reference stream rather than table.  Does anyone know of any unix/linux-based utilities to convert a PDF to an older version?  Or perhaps there's a Perl module in CPAN I missed that can handle this?

Answer (score 14):

Done!  An hour ago, I uploaded CAM::PDF v1.50 to CPAN. It now supports PDF v1.5 compressed object streams and cross-reference streams. I've tested it with a few PDF files that I found online, but I'd sure appreciate feedback (good or bad).

Comment: Upvote for cross-reference streams.  Only the newest versions of PDF::API2 can handle that.

Answer (score 1):

I would try running it through ghostscript with appropriate parameters.

Something like `gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwriter -dCompatibilityLevel=1.2`

Comment: Note this will also lose things such as transparency information.

Comment: Also, it will flatten out any text in the file into vector paths, so the resulting PDF is worthless if you want to be able to futher edit the text in a vector graphics or DTP program that can import PDFs.